# ArcGIS - How to find street map labels for separate layer

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps, streets

I'm super new to GIS mapping. I just installed the trial of ArcGIS and I've just barely begun poking around in ArcGIS Online trying to figure out what I'm capable of. I'd like to have a street map (at least of US and Canada) and then overlay various data on top of it in separate layers. I've already overlayed radar data from the National Weather Service, for example.

My problem is that since the street names are embedded on the basemap, it's impossible to see them when covered by the weather data.

I saw that there are a couple stock basemaps that include labels in a separate layer like "Terrain with Labels" and "Imagery with Labels" where I can position my weather, crime data, etc. in between the basemap and the labels.

Are there basemaps available somewhere that allow me to do this with street names instead of just imagery/terrain data?

Comment: Why not enable transparency (e.g. 40%, 50%, 60%....) on your weather data so you can see slightly through it and still see the underlying basemap labels?

Comment: I could do that, certainly. The underlying labels are harder to read that way, though. One of the layers I currently have is crime data and it renders colored polygons of various color intensity (depending on how bad the crime in that neighborhood is) over the entire face of the US. Changing its transparency makes it more difficult to interpret. The ideal solution would be to have the labels as the top-most layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe ArcGIS Online's [World Transportation](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=94f838a535334cf1aa061846514b77c7) layer is exactly what you are looking for.

[image: World transportation]